# How to sort multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array as follows

```
var arry = [ [1, "Convention Hall", "Mumbai", 10, "XYZ Company"], 
             [2, "Auditorium", "Delhi", 10, "ABC Company"], 
             [3, "CenterHall", "Bangalore", 10, "ZZZ Company"],
            ....
            ]
```

I want to sort the array alphabetically based on the third item of array i.e **arry[n][2]**

How to do this.

Comment: So, its already sorted in this case?

Comment: `arry.sort(function (a, b) { return a[2] - b[2]; });`

Comment: It's already sorted in this case, but check my answer. I changed city names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/VPrAr/

[image]

You can use the `arry.sort()`. The default is alphanumeric and ascending.

So it would be:

```
var arry = [ [1, "Convention Hall", "Dangalore", 10, "XYZ Company"], 
             [2, "Auditorium", "Belhi", 10, "ABC Company"], 
             [3, "CenterHall", "Aumbai", 10, "ZZZ Company"],
            ];
var x =arry.sort(function(a,b){ return a[2] > b[2] ? 1 : -1; });
alert(x);
```

Comment: Since sort is mutator method there's no need to assign it to new variable, and what about `a[2] === b[2]`?

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function expects a function as a parameter, which accepts two parameters and returns any of `-1, 0 or 1`.

I am a very big fan of functional programming, so I came up with this. This offers flexibility.

1. You can sort based on any element
2. You can even reverse the order of sorting
3. You can customize, how the objects have to be compared.

---

```
function basicComparator(first, second) {
    if (first === second) {
        return 0;
    } else if (first < second) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

function compareNthElements(n, comparatorFunction, reverse) {
    return function(first, second) {
        if (reverse === true) {
            return comparatorFunction(second[n], first[n]);
        } else {
            return comparatorFunction(first[n], second[n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thats it. Now, call the `sort` function like this

```
arry.sort(compareNthElements(1, basicComparator, true));  // Sorts first field and in reverse
arry.sort(compareNthElements(2, basicComparator));        // Sorts second field
```

Comment: Why not simply `return first - second;`?

Comment: @Givi It may not work properly for all data types. For example, if both the elements being compared are objects, it will return `NaN`. So, I made the function more flexible, to pass the comparator function as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a sort function for example:

```
arry.sort(function(a,b){
   return a[2] > b[2] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//WITH FIRST COLUMN
     arry = arry.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a[0] > b[0];
    });


//WITH SECOND COLUMN
arry = arry.sort(function(a,b) {
 return a[1] > b[1];
 });


//WITH THIRD COLUMN
//and you want this code below
arry = arry.sort(function(a,b) {
 return a[2] > b[2];
 });
```